# missing template arguments only on raspberry-pi platform

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, g++, cross-compiling

I wrote a simple queue as below:

```
#pragma once

#include <mutex>
#include <queue>

template <typename T>
class MessagesQueuee
{
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::queue<T> queue;
public:
    MessagesQueuee() {};
    ~MessagesQueuee() {};

    void push(T&& item)
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
        queue.push(item);
    }

    T& front() {
        std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
        return queue.front();
    }

    void pop() {
        std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
        queue.pop();
    }
};
```

which is part of bigger project.
It compiles succesfully on my ubuntu (amd64) with g++.
But when i try to compile it on raspberry pi: it gives the error:

```
missing template arguments before lock
```

pointing to lines:

```
std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
```

I even don't know where to look for a solution, or even: how to name it.
Is there anything wrong with the code?
If so, how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Make sure you're using C++17, since that's when class template argument deduction was added.  If your compiler doesn't support C++17 then use `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);`.

Comment: It needs `-std=c++17` or `-std=gnu++17` at least.

Comment: Since you know which line to focus on, did you try to reduce your [mre] to just that line? E.g.: `#include <mutex> int main() { std::mutex mutex;
std::lock_guard lock(mutex); /* Do stuff */
}`